# A better Java loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a piece of code to read a `InputStream` and write the content into an `OutputStream`:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(...);
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream outStream(...);

int read = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
while (read != -1) {
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
    read = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}
```

It works, but i don't like it since the variable `read` is declared out of the loop, and `read()` method is written twice.
The revised version:

```
 for (int read = 0; read != -1; read = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) {
      outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
 }
```

It looks better but not good enough because the first iteration is useless (and maybe harmful) with read=0.

Do you have a better solution?

Comment: IMHO the first version is far more readable than the second version.

Comment: or you could just use commons-io and replace the whole thing with `IOUtils.copy(in, outStream);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I break the normal "no side-effect in a condition" rule for this sort of thing:

```
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != -1)
{
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

EDIT: As noted, it *does* involve declaring `read` outside the loop, but it only calls `read()` once. I've never found it to be a problem - while I generally prefer to declare variables with as small a scope as possible, that's more a general cleanliness thing. If you want to limit the scope further you can put the whole thing in braces, or extract it to its own method, like Alan's approach. Here's how I'd implement it though:

```
public static void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
    throws IOException {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 16]; // Reasonable general size

  int bytesRead;
  while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could provide the buffer length as a parameter. Note that this can now go off into a utility library, and you need never write the code again.

Alternatively, you could use the fact that it's already available in other utility libraries, such as [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) as [`ByteStreams.copy`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)

Comment: This still requires `bytesRead` to be declared outside the loop, which was explicitly not wanted.

Comment: well, this answer is generally the same as the one from Mat (and both at the almost same time). But why this one has got much more vote-ups? only because it is Jon? Or you've read something that i had not seen?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(...);
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream outStream(...);

while (true) { // can i use for(;;) in Java ???
    int read = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    if (read == -1) break;
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

It uses a `break`, though. Some people say `break` is bad/not so good style.

Comment: my old cs-teacher always told me: *"It's like getting out of the airplane with the ejection seat"*. imho: it depends on the loop. In this case, it doesn't make any sense to use break and while is the better option (see other answers).

Comment: @Simon: isn't `break` here a kind of [guard clause](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html)?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, this option avoids `read` having a larger scope than necessary. I agree that is not very important.

Comment: yes, `for (;;)` is valid in Java - compiles to the same as `while (true)`

Comment: @wang.xueqiang Yes it is, but `while(true)` is a really bad style. Just use the answer Jon Skeet provided, it's the common way.

Answer (score 3):

It's not brilliant, but with a simple block, you can stop the `read` variable from being accessed later in the method:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(...);
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream outStream(...);

{
    int read = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (read != -1)
    {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        read = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }
}

// ...rest of your code
```

...but I agree, I've also often wanted a while loop where the value to be tested is initialized inside the loop. As far as I know, it's not possible.

Another way to do it is to use the [extract method design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-method) to pull out that loop in to a completely separate method, i.e.

```
public void yourMethod() {
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(...);
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream outStream(...);

    this.writeToOutputStream(in, outStream);
}

private void writeToOutputStream(InputStream in, OutputStream outStream) {
    int read = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (read != -1)
    {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        read = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This form is rather usual:

```
while ((read = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
  ...
}
```

but not so good for clarity IMO.

Comment: My second version is not recommended, is it?

Comment: @wang: in my opinion it's even less readable, and you are correct in pointing out that the first iteration is wrong. this version is quite usual, you'll see it a lot so other people reading your code shouldn't be too puzzled.